# Is there a .NET library that can sign a request with AWS V4 Signature?

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-api-gateway, aws-lambda

I have an API Gateway where I'm setting the authentication to use AWS_IAM.  This requires that I sign each request with the AWS V4 signature and attach the HMAC in the header.  I've found libraries to sign a request with the V4 signature in nodejs.  But I cannot find a library to sign for me.  Even the aws-sdk for .NET has this abstracted for their own specific use case.  Is there a library out there (i've done a quick google search and found no results)?  Or do I need to write out the hmac myself?

Comment: Is the [standard library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/hmac.html#module-hmac) not applicable for this?

Comment: The implementation will definitely use the standard .net library to perform the actual HMAC, but the recipe for how to generate the key and what to hmac is involved.  https://github.com/mhart/aws4/blob/master/aws4.js is the nodejs implementation that signs a request for aws v4 signature.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can read on how the signature is done and you can (if you want).
I would recommend pulling in the AWS SDK for .NET and using the functionality from the SDK to actually perform the signature.

Here is the signer form the SDK:

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/blob/6c3be79bdafd5bfff1ab0bf5fec17abc66c7b516/sdk/src/Core/Amazon.Runtime/Internal/Auth/AWS4Signer.cs

You may need to adapt it (ie it knows about AWS services and endpoints by default)

Comment: Their library will speed along the process, but I still have to shoe horn the standard HttpRequestMessage into their IRequest format or at least write a wrapper to return similiar parameters.

Comment: We (API Gateway) are aware of the need for official .NET SDK support and have prioritized accordingly. In the meantime, I would suggest as @Mircea suggested and to either 1) Implement your own signer as per http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4_signing.html or 2) Re-use pieces of the existing .NET AWS SDK

Comment: Hi, I'm the co author of this library and can accept requests or feedback.

Answer (score 11):

While this is an old question, since AWS has not "prioritized accordingly" with regards to the .NET AWS SDK as stated in their comment above and this is still a relevant problem today, I found a good library that will take care of the AWS V4 request signing for you.

[Here is the Nuget package.](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Aws4RequestSigner/)

[Here is the GitHub source and implementation documentation.](https://github.com/tsibelman/aws-signer-v4-dot-net)

In addition, I've found that for my API Gateway AWS_IAM Authorization to work with temporary security credentials, you also need to include the "x-amz-security-token" header with the current session token as it's value as well in your request.

Answer (score 6):

An alternative to [Aws4RequestSigner](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Aws4RequestSigner/) is [AwsSignatureVersion4](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AwsSignatureVersion4/). I think its API is easier to work with, but I am biased since I am the author of the latter.

Comment: Hi, I am using AWS elasticsearch and would like to sign the requests. I am using the asp .net elasticsearch NEST sdk and was wondering if your AwsSignatureVersion4 would work with that?    var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

Comment: I actually have no idea, but it would be fun to try out! Would you be able to create a GitHub repository with sample code, and we could see if we can work together on it?

Comment: I have an IAM secured API Gateway stage and want to make requests to it from a lambda function, using that lambda function's IAM role and I'm wondering if I can do that using either of these libraries? Any guidance would be appreciated as I'm not seeing how to do that presently. Thanks.

Comment: Aren't AWS IAM roles set as environment variables on the Lambda function? In that case you should be able to use those in requests using AwsSignatureVersion4.

Answer (score 1):

When using SSO authentication, you also have a session token that you need to include in the http request.

After signing the request, add the session token inside the http header `x-amz-security-token`.

Here is an example of implementing this inside a search request:

```
var baseUrl = "es_url";
var indexName = "index_name";
var requestUri = new Uri($"{baseUrl}/{indexName}/_search");

var req = new HttpRequestMessage
{
    RequestUri = requestUri,
    Method = System.Net.Http.HttpMethod.Post,
    Content = new StringContent(query, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
};

var accessKeyId = "ACCESS_KEY";
var secretKey = "SECRET_KEY"
var sessionToken = "SESSION_TOKEN";

var signer = new AWS4RequestSigner(accessKeyId, secretKey);
req = await signer.Sign(req, "es", "us-west-2");

req.Headers.Add("x-amz-security-token", sessionToken);

var client = new HttpClient();
var response = await client.SendAsync(req);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. This question is asked more than 9 years ago and it has an accepted answer. Please add some details about the reason you are adding a new answer.