# AWS V4 Signing of .NET HttpClient

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, authentication

I need to call an AWS Gateway API service that is secured with AWS_IAM.

I want to use `HttpClient` as this is the recommended way by Microsoft.

I have found some example code using other ways. I've also found the official AWS SDK that uses their internal IRequest. I'm currently writing an implementation of IRequest so I can use `Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Auth.AWS4Signer.SignRequest`. But this seems incredibly hacky!

What I really want is something that will take my `HttpClient`, then inject the Host, X-Amz-Content-SHA256, X-Amz-Date and Authorization headers.

I find it hard to believe there is not a ready-to-use library already existing.

Note that this is similar to this question, but it is a bit old and I would have hoped there would be an easier way now. [Is there a .NET library that can sign a request with AWS V4 Signature?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37217532/is-there-a-net-library-that-can-sign-a-request-with-aws-v4-signature)

---

Update 2018-03-21 - there is now a NuGet package https://www.nuget.org/packages/Aws4RequestSigner/

My colleague has used this and reports it to work well! I hope this is of help to anyone arriving at this question.

Comment: Thanks! I will try this package asap, it's crazy how aws + c# has no updated example anywhere!

Comment: I still have difficulties to understand how to use it properly, if you have an example to share (from your co-worker for example), It could be really great! (byt the way this way you could answer yourself and accept your answer...)